# Go to another page and load ajax call on that page via href

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, hyperlink

On page 1 I have a navigation with links which calls ajax and lists all portfolio items in that category

nav links look like this:

```
<nav class="pos-relative filter filter-underline">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="all ajax" data-object="portfolio" data-view="list-grid-textbelow" data-section="project-list" data-category-id="*" data-limit="50" data-noresult-message="No more result found.">
                All</a>
    <div class="loading" style="display: none;"></div>
    <a href="#arhitecture" class="ajax active" id="cat-filter-arhitecture" data-object="portfolio" data-view="list-grid-textbelow" data-section="project-list" data-category-id="16" data-limit="50" data-noresult-message="No more result found.">
                        Arhitecture</a>
    <div class="loading"></div>
    <a href="#design" class="ajax" id="cat-filter-design" data-object="portfolio" data-view="list-grid-textbelow" data-section="project-list" data-category-id="19" data-limit="50" data-noresult-message="No more result found.">
                        Design</a>
    <div class="loading"></div>
</nav>
```

Js used for this:

```
/* ========================================================================
 * DOM-based Routing
 * Based on http://goo.gl/EUTi53 by Paul Irish
 *
 * Only fires on body classes that match. If a body class contains a dash,
 * replace the dash with an underscore when adding it to the object below.
 *
 * .noConflict()
 * The routing is enclosed within an anonymous function so that you can 
 * always reference jQuery with $, even when in .noConflict() mode.
 *
 * Google CDN, Latest jQuery
 * To use the default WordPress version of jQuery, go to lib/config.php and
 * remove or comment out: add_theme_support('jquery-cdn');
 * ======================================================================== */

(function($) {

"use strict";

// Projects list view (Portfolio)
var project_list = function () {
    // if found #hash in URL,
    //    get ID of category, and in found cat_id, than, ajax start
},

// Use this variable to set up the common and page specific functions. If you 
// rename this variable, you will also need to rename the namespace below.
Roots = {
  // All pages
  common: {
    init: function() {
        // JavaScript to be fired on all pages

        // ajax event
        $('a.ajax').click( function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var $linkAjaxClicked = $(this), $navLinkAjaxClicked;
                // navigation of filter links
                $navLinkAjaxClicked = $linkAjaxClicked.parent('nav').length ? $linkAjaxClicked.parent('nav') : $linkAjaxClicked.parent().parent('nav');

                if (typeof $linkAjaxClicked.data('section') === 'undefined' ||
                    typeof $linkAjaxClicked.data('object') === 'undefined' ||
                    typeof $linkAjaxClicked.data('limit') === 'undefined') {
                        console.log('AJAX ERROR: Missing some required data. Required HTML5 data-* attributes are: "data-section", "data-object" and "data-limit".');
                        return false;
                }

                var $parentSection = $('section.' + $linkAjaxClicked.data('section')), // parent <section> class name
                    $answerContainer = $('#' + $linkAjaxClicked.data('object') + '-ajax-data'), // answer data container ID
                    ajaxData = window[ $linkAjaxClicked.data('object') ], // ajax WP config data object
                    view = typeof $linkAjaxClicked.data('view') !== 'undefined' ? $linkAjaxClicked.data('view') : 0, // view of file e.g. portfolio-"LIST-GRID".php
                    reponse_action = typeof $linkAjaxClicked.data('adding') !== 'undefined' ?
                        $linkAjaxClicked.data('adding') :
                        'replace', // append | replace
                    data2send = {}, $item, limit = $linkAjaxClicked.data('limit'),
                    offset = typeof $linkAjaxClicked.data('offset') !== 'undefined' ? $linkAjaxClicked.data('offset') : 0,
                    categoryId = typeof $linkAjaxClicked.data('category-id') !== 'undefined' ?
                        $linkAjaxClicked.data('category-id') :
                        '*',
                    $btnMore = $parentSection.find('.btn-more'), $btnLoading = $btnMore.next('.loading'),
                    $containerLoading = $('<div class="loading"></div>'), $filterLoading = $parentSection.find('.filter .loading').first(),
                    noResultMessage = typeof $linkAjaxClicked.data('noresult-message') !== 'undefined' ?
                        $linkAjaxClicked.data('noresult-message') :
                        'No more result found.',
                    offsetSource = typeof $linkAjaxClicked.data('offset-source') !== 'undefined' ?
                        $linkAjaxClicked.data('offset-source') :
                        false;

                // set category ID on "load more" button
                $parentSection.find('.btn-more').data('category-id', categoryId);

                // select "active" filter navigation link
                if ( $navLinkAjaxClicked.length ) {
                    $navLinkAjaxClicked.find('.ajax').removeClass('active');
                    $linkAjaxClicked.addClass('active');
                }

                // loading effect
                //$linkAjaxClicked.append('<i class="icon-spinner animate-spin"></i>');
                $btnLoading.show();
                $filterLoading.show();
                if ( reponse_action === 'replace' ) { // only when we replace content, this content is blocked during AJAX loading
                    $containerLoading.appendTo($answerContainer).fadeIn();
                }

                if (offsetSource === 'item') {
                    $item = $answerContainer.find('.item');
                    offset = $item.length;
                }

                // data sending by ajax
                data2send = {
                    action: ajaxData.action,
                    view: view,
                    limit: limit,
                    offset: offset,
                    nonce: ajaxData.nonce,
                    catid: categoryId,
                    pagination: false
                };
                // ajax start
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: ajaxData.url,
                    data: data2send,
                    complete: function () {
                        // turn off loader effect
                        $linkAjaxClicked.find('.icon-spinner').remove();
                        $btnLoading.hide();
                        $filterLoading.hide();
                        $containerLoading.hide();
                    },
                    success: function ( response ) {

                        if ( response === '' ) { // empty response
                            var extracss = $answerContainer.hasClass('masonry') ? 'item' : 'hide-item';
                            response  = '<div class="col-xs-12 '+extracss+'">';
                            response += '    <div class="text-center text-upper alert alert-info">'+noResultMessage+'</div>';
                            response += '</div>';
                        }

                        var $response = $(response);

                        if ( reponse_action === 'replace') { // default action
                            $answerContainer
                                .html( $response )
                                .find('.hide-item').fadeIn('normal');

                        } else if ( reponse_action === 'append') {
                            $answerContainer
                                .append( $response )
                                .find('.hide-item').fadeIn('slow');
                        }

                        if ( response !== '' ) {
                            // animate.css
                            animate.setDelay( $('.animated') ); // again setted .animated elements, because it is new elements generated by AJAX
                            animate.start( animate.itemsInside($answerContainer) );

                            // set Magnific Popup  [http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/]
                            // definition of "setMagnificPopup" function is on the top of main.js file
                            $answerContainer.find('.magnific-gallery').each(setMagnificPopup);

                            // jQuery panr [https://github.com/robbue/jquery.panr]
                            // definition of "configPanr" object is on the top of main.js file
                            var $wppostimage = $('.no-touch .wp-post-image');
                            if (typeof $wppostimage.panr === 'function' && $wppostimage.length) {
                                $wppostimage.panr(configPanr);
                            }

                            // WordPress-Post-Like-System  [https://github.com/JonMasterson/WordPress-Post-Like-System]
                            // definition of "setLikeSystem" function is on the top of main.js file
                            $answerContainer.find('.jm-post-like').click(setLikeSystem);

                            // Masonry  [http://masonry.desandro.com/]
                            if ( $answerContainer.hasClass('masonry') ) {

                                if ( reponse_action === 'replace') { // default action
                                    $answerContainer
                                        .masonry('destroy')
                                        .imagesLoaded( function() {
                                            $answerContainer.masonry({
                                                itemSelector: '.item'
                                            });
                                        });
                                } else if ( reponse_action === 'append') {
                                    $answerContainer
                                        .imagesLoaded( function() {
                                            $answerContainer.masonry('appended', $response);
                                        });
                                }
                            }
                            // Owl Carousel 2  [http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/]
                            // definition of "setOwlCarousel" function is on the top of main.js file
                            else if ( $answerContainer.hasClass('owl-carousel') ) {
                                $answerContainer.trigger('destroy.owl.carousel');
                                $answerContainer.each(setOwlCarousel);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
        });
    }
  },
  // Home page
  home: {
    init: function() {
      // JavaScript to be fired on the home page
    }
  },
  // Portfolio: Project List
  page_template_list_fullscr_portfolio_php: {
    init: project_list
  },
  // Portfolio: Project List
  page_template_list_grid_portfolio_php: {
    init: project_list
  },
};

// The routing fires all common scripts, followed by the page specific scripts.
// Add additional events for more control over timing e.g. a finalize event
var UTIL = {
  fire: function(func, funcname, args) {
    var namespace = Roots;
    funcname = (funcname === undefined) ? 'init' : funcname;
    if (func !== '' && namespace[func] && typeof namespace[func][funcname] === 'function') {
      namespace[func][funcname](args);
    }
  },
  loadEvents: function() {
    UTIL.fire('common');

    $.each(document.body.className.replace(/-/g, '_').split(/\s+/),function(i,classnm) {
      UTIL.fire(classnm);
    });
  }
};

$(document).ready(UTIL.loadEvents);

})(jQuery); // Fully reference jQuery after this point.
```

Now I want to make a link on page 2, which will take me to page 1 and call that ajax and display the desired category (lets say design).

I tried to insert a href and link it to the http://somesite/page1/#design but ofcourse it does not work. It loads page 1 but ajax is not called. What should I include for that link to work?

Comment: can you add your Jquery which calls the ajax on click of the anchor tag? it would be easier to give you solution that way

Comment: Yes, I have added it.@Reddy

Comment: ok, so your page 2 means the page loaded via ajax right?

Comment: My page 2 is ordinary page which need to contain a link to page 1. That link leads to page 1 and activates ajax call.@Reddy I will try your solution now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you are redirecting from page 2 to page 1 and then you want to show the desired category say `#design`. Here is what you can do.

On your page 2 when ever you `click on the link` which will take you to the page 1, Just before the ajax call `set the category link in a` **localstorage** like below.

```
localStorage.setItem("categoryLink", '#design ');  // here #design is hardcoded but you have to make it dynamic.
```

Then you can add this in your page 1 document ready script.

```
   $(function(){
     var categoryHref = localStorage.getItem("categoryLink") // get the value from storage
     if(categoryHref ){ // if the value exists
       $('a[href="'+categoryHref  +'"]').trigger('click'); 
       localStorage.removeItem("categoryLink"); // remove it after first use    
     }
   });
```

So the idea is to find the anchor tag with the Href `#design` and trigger a click, which will automatically call the ajax which you already have in place

**EDIT 1 :** since you asked how to set the local storage value dynamically, here is my answer.

I assume you have a anchor tag which you call as link and it takes the user to a different page.

```
<a href='someURL' data-target-category='#design'>Click Me</a>
```

Maintain a `data-` attribute like this which will hold the category href value. Now onlick of this link we need to save to local storage, Like below

```
 $('a').on('click',function(){ //change the selectors according to your HTML
   localStorage.setItem("categoryLink", $(this).data('target-category')); // dynamic assignment       
 });
```

Comment: I am not calling ajax on page 2? (Just before the ajax call set the category link in a localstorage like below.) @Reddy

Comment: The idea is to go from some page A(totally different from page B) to page B and fire up ajax on page B, deppending on the href value from page 2 @Reddy

Comment: Yes ok then, you must just figure out a point where you can set the value to the local storage.

Comment: Just make sure you set the value and in your page B you can always check if any value exist in the local storage, if yes then trigger click else do nothing.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem, I understand the second part, but I don't know where to implement localStorage and how to make it dynamic. "#design" should be generated deppending on a href title for example. Here is the single portfolio page: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oxXPXO

Comment: I owe you a beer :) It works, but with a small bug. Any idea how to clear categoryHref after load? It sees that value is there, takes it and clears it? If I dont clear it, then everytime page 1 loads, it does not show all projects, but that last one from categoryHref.

Comment: @MarcSommerson I update the deletion code too. And where is my Beer :)

Comment: it's coming :) localStorage is now removed and no data is stored with new code? How does it know to remove it after first use? It's removed instantly?

Comment: oh, sorry I made a mistake,, I had to put it in another place, I am editing my answer now.

Comment: I got it, it's good, you wrote it at wrong location. Should go at page 1script after value is taken. Many thanks for your time!

Comment: also check spell error 'target-categoty', someone might use this. Cheers!

Comment: Guess I gave you a homework by writing in wrong place :). I fixed it now. And glad to know I could help you.